# Cosa significa "allappare il cervello"?

Tags: verbs, meaning

Nel romanzo *Rossovermiglio* di Benedetta Cibrario ho letto:

> Se capisse, gli direi che tutte le lacrime – e non solo quelle per Enrico – che non possono solcarti le guance se ne vanno da un'altra parte, scavano dentro, sotterranee come certi fiumi, anzi, incanalate così hanno una forza e una violenza che brucia e corrode, consuma il cuore e **allappa il cervello** come i cachi acerbi.

Ho cercato il [significato del verbo "allappare" nel vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/allappare/) e ho trovato:

> Allegare i denti, dare alla bocca la sensazione acre che producono i frutti aspri o acerbi: *un sugo che allappa la bocca* (o assol. *che allappa*); *un sapore amarognolo gli allappava il palato* (Cicognani).

Tuttavia, non capisco il senso di "allappare il cervello" nel brano precedente. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il significato è quello descritto ma viene usato in senso figurato. Mangiare   un frutto  acerbo provoca  una sensazione astringente, come se la bocca fosse legata e incapace di svolgere la propria funzione normalmente. Per analogia un cervello "allappato" è un cervello incapace di funzionare come dovrebbe.

***Allappare:***

> - provocare una sensazione astringente in bocca come se i denti e la lingua fossero legati, effetto tipico della frutta aspra o non matura e di alcuni sali
>     *il cachi acerbo allappa particolarmente*

Wiktionary

Un'espressione piu comune e' "offuscare il cervello o la mente".